# help with python code please?

Tags: python, windows

Why is the last item not displayed in the interpreter?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

**Za4kar 011**, потому что input() возвращает строку, а не число

Вам надо сделать или `d == '2'` или `int( d ) == 2`